# how can I change these div elements nested inside other div's?

Tags: css

I'm working with google maps infowindow style and I want to change some div's css that is automatically generated.

How can I change these sections using only css ?

```
<div class="gm-style">
 <div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div>
    <div>         /*  <--------------  I wanto to change this one */
      <div></div> /*  <--------------  And this */
      <div class="gm-style-iw"></div>
    </div>
    /*(...)*/ 
   </div>
   /*(...)*/
  </div>
 </div>
 /*(...)*/
</div>
```

Obs: I don't want to use javascript because it needs to use some functions from google library that I'm struggling with ([Listening infowindow with Gmaps4rails gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233040/listening-infowindow-with-gmaps4rails-gem)).

Comment: I think, the only way that is gonna work is inserting styles through javascript, otherwise the css it's gonna be ignored because google probably is adding their own syles to that.  by the way, try to use !important property

Comment: I thought that it could be in this way but I tested and actually works by css

Answer (score 1):

Using `nth-of-type` selector may work for you.

```css
.gm-style>div>div:nth-of-type(4)>div:nth-of-type(4)>div {
  color: red;
}

/* is nested inside targetted div */
.gm-style-iw {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="gm-style">
  <div>
    <div>Not this</div>
    <div>Not this</div>
    <div>Not this</div>
    <div>
      <div>Not this</div>
      <div>Not this</div>
      <div>Not this</div>
      <div>
        <div> I wanto to change this one
          <div>And this</div>
          <div class="gm-style-iw">*Not this</div>
        </div>
        Not this
      </div>
      Not this
    </div>
  </div>
  Not this
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers and getting something from your code, this is what solved my problem:

```
.gm-style>div>div:nth-of-type(4)>div:nth-of-type(4)>div {
  /* something */
}

.gm-style>div>div:nth-of-type(4)>div:nth-of-type(4)>div>div:first-of-type {
  /* something */
}
```